# Adding div inside long echo string php

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to add a div inside this echo string, looked at all the other topics but this string is a bit more complex than the issues discussed there.

**Whole code:**

```
          <div class="breadcrumb hidden-xs" typeof="BreadcrumbList" vocab="https://schema.org/">     
          <span property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem"><a property="item" typeof="WebPage" class="home" href="<?php echo home_url('/');?>" title="<?php echo bloginfo('name');?>"><span property="name">Home</span></a><meta property="position" content="1"></span><span class="division">/</span><span property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem"><a property="item" typeof="WebPage" class="post-root post post-post" href="<?php echo home_url('/blog/');?>" title="Ga naar Nieuws."><span property="name">Nieuws</span></a><meta property="position" content="2"></span><span class="division">/</span>
    <span property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem">
                <?php
$categories = get_the_category();
$separator = ',';
$output = '';
if($categories){
  $i=1;
  foreach($categories as $category) {
      if($i==1){
      if($category->cat_name!="Homepage"){
    echo '<a property="item" typeof="WebPage" href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>';
  $i++; } } } } ?>
      <meta property="position" content="3"></span>
    <span class="division">/</span><span property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem"><span property="name"><?php the_title();?></span><meta property="position" content="4"></span></div>
```

**Code i need to edit:**

```
echo '<a property="item" typeof="WebPage" href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>';
```

So i like to add this `<span property="name">` before the .$category->cat_name.

And the closing `</span>` before the closing `</a>`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look into how string concatenation in PHP works, then you'll be able to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i got it already:

```
echo '<a property="item" typeof="WebPage" href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">' . '<span property="name">'.$category->cat_name.'</span></a>';
```